# SQL Query show everything after a certain date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do an sql-query in which i want to get every entry after a certain date. The dates are in format "mm.yyyy". I tried the following thing which is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND ez >= '02.2002'
```

i think the problem is that it is only trying to compare the first to numbers with each other, but i am not 100% sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you storing dates as strings?  And if so, why aren't you storing them in a YYYYMM format?

Comment: I am not responsible for how the data is stored in the database, i get it like this. There are already over 1500 entrys, so i don`t think the person i get it form will change anything.

Comment: Can you show us an *example* row or two, or even better - the relevant `CREATE TABLE` statement - so that we know the structure of the table this query is operating on.

Comment: Looks like data is stored right way, you'd better convert filter parameter to a regular date format. This also will let everyone better understand what means "after 02.2002": does it >= 01.02.2002 or >= 01.03.2002 (after February). Append '01.' to the beginning of your parameter, avoid conversions and let server use appropriate index.

Comment: If you really must save them as a string, using the 'year-month-day' format allows you to compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a standard date format:

```
WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND
      concat(right(ez, 4), left(ez, 2)) >= '200202'
```

Comment: @Marcel Wasilewski Please **accept** an answer if it worked for you.  This allows other StackOverflow users whom find this page and have similar problems.